# Open window only for certain countries

Tags: localization, location

For the new gdpr law i am forced to notify the users in europe.

Now i would like to only show this notification to the users in europe.

Whats the best way to do this?

Im using C# and unity3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... This is almost the solution...
At first, I thought I could use:

```
System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion
```

But it turned out that he always displays the "US".
Then I found this plugin:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/precise-locale-65836

There libraries for native platforms are used.

```
PreciseLocale.GetRegion()
```

It is necessary to compare the received region with:

```
"BE", "EL", "LT", "PT", "BG", "ES", "LU", "RO", "CZ", "FR", "HU", "SI", "DK", "HR", "MT", "SK", "DE", "IT", "NL", "FI", "EE", "CY", "AT", "SE", "IE", "LV", "PL", "UK", "CH", "NO", "IS", "LI"
```

Then it remains only to copy the text from the Google's example:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent

and write the code for "npa".

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder() .AddExtra("npa", "1") .Build();
```

(Sending a value of  "1" will serve non-personalized ads)